# Windows incremential copy files keeping all versions with datetime in filename

Tags: windows, backup, sync, file-transfer

I need to track changes to folders with files like jpg or docx, and make a copy to another folder.

I need to make a copy of the file when it changes, keeping the filename and adding the current datetime.

SOURCE:
mydoc.docx

TARGET:

mydoc.20111224080000.docx //Changed at 08:00:00

And if I change mydoc.docx a little later target would look like this:

TARGET:

mydoc.20111224080000.docx //Changed at 08:00:00

mydoc.20111224080200.docx //Changed at 08:02:00

The comparison should allways be against the newest file in the TARGET folder.

I need to run in the background, monitoring the folder og in time intervals.

Is there a program that I can use?

Answer (score 2):

One type of program you could use is a [version control program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). They were originally designed for keeping track of changes to source code, but you can use them with virtually any type of file.

You put all the files you want to have version of into it and then when you edit the file it basically takes a copy. You need to remember to check the file back into the repository for each version you want to keep.

You can get any version back out of the system and anyone you give access to can edit the files as well.

Comment: You could setup a VCS to auto add/commit changes with a scheduled task if he wants to skip the manual commit part.

Comment: No dice. I need the files raw in the file system. So that I can copy them later.

Comment: @MortenLyhr - There may be a way to do this dependant on the system you use, but it might be more complicated than you need.